# Example of ideal generated by two elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I have an easy example on my notes that I don't understand. My teacher said that in $\mathbb{Z}$, $(2,3)=2\mathbb{Z}+3\mathbb{Z}$ is a principal ideal, because $2\mathbb{Z}+3\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$. How she could say that without proving it? What am I overlooking? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $1 = 3 - 2 \in 2\mathbb Z + 3\mathbb Z$, hence so is all of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: 3 - 2 = 1, so 3Z + 2Z = Z

Comment: She can say it because it is true. It is provable rather easily by showing that $1$ is in the ideal. However $\mathbb Z$ is a Principal Ideal Domain so any ideal will be principal - e.g. the ideal generated by $60$ and $126$ will be principal.

Comment: $n = 3n - 2n \in  3\Bbb Z + 2\Bbb Z\ \ $

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $3+-2=1 \in (3,2)$, hence the generated ideal contains $1$, hence it contains $\mathbb Z$

Answer (score 2):

Let $d=gcd(a,b)$. Then $a\mathbb{Z}+b\mathbb{Z}=d\mathbb{Z}$, since the Euclidean algorithm yields integers $r,s$ with $ra+sb=d$. Hence $2\mathbb{Z}+3\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb Z$, every ideal is principal.